# Spring Framework, enable PUT method

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-method

I got a problem with capturing PUT request sent to server.

These are my methods:

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)  
public String getCity(@PathVariable(value="cid") String cid, @RequestParam(value="State") Integer state,  Model model) {
    System.out.println("get request");  
    return "index";  
}


@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.PUT)  
public String putCity(@PathVariable(value="cid") String cid, @RequestParam(value="State") Integer state, Model model) {
    System.out.println("put request");
    return "index";
}
```

When I traced the call, my PUT request was handled by GET method and not by PUT method in my class.. on out screen, it always read as "get request". I've checked the browser log and confirms that they sent the correct PUT request, so I think I've missed some Spring configuration here, but I don't know what  it is..

Can someone please help?

Thank you.

EDIT: Additional code with class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/retail/{cid}/master/city")
public class City {

    @RequestMapping(value="/foo1", method= RequestMethod.GET)  
    public String getCity(@PathVariable(value="cid") String cid, @RequestParam(value="State")   Integer state,  Model model) {
        System.out.println("get request");  
        return "index";  
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/foo2", method= RequestMethod.PUT)  
    public String putCity(@PathVariable(value="cid") String cid, @RequestParam(value="State") Integer state, Model model) {
        System.out.println("put request");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

EDIT2:
Sorry, it seems I didn't very thorough when examining the log.. I caught this warning twice.

```
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
```

any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: If `getCity` is being invoked, then the request is a `GET` method. No additional config is required, you must be sending the wrong kind of request. Are you sure your client is doing the right thing?

Comment: yes.. I am sure the client was doing the right thing. It was being logged into the console. Tried with chrome and firefox, and both sent PUT request.

Comment: Add an `HttpServletRequest` parameter to `getCity`, then log `request.getMethod()`, and see what that says.

Comment: Are you sure your client is sending a PUT request?

Comment: Yes.. the client did sent a `PUT` request.. Anyway, thanks to skaffman. I have modified my code slightly removing all `@RequestParam` and replacing them with `HttpServletRequest` and the result goes to `putCity` method. This is odd, but it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: Replaced `@RequestParam` with `HttpServletRequest`, I tried to find the form parameters, but I always got null? getParameterMap() gave me empty map. I am sure the form data was there. A couple to be exact. My browser log also confirmed that I sent the parameter.

Comment: Ok.. I tried to make a small Ruby script to check the parameters, and Ruby did receive it correctly. So, browser is not the problem here. The client should send `state` as form parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is solved... This is the revised method that works

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/retail/{cid}/master/city")
public class City {

  @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)  
  public String getCity(@PathVariable(value="cid") String cid, @RequestParam(value="State") Integer state, Model model) {
    System.out.println("get request");  
    return "index";  
  }

  @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.PUT)  
  public String putCity(@PathVariable(value="cid") String cid, @RequestBody CityData state, Model model) {
    System.out.println(state.getState());
    return "index";
  }
}
```

```
public class CityData {
  private String state;
  public String getState() {
    return this.state;
  }
  public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
  }
}
```

You could use `@RequestBody String state`, but I prefer to create CityData object because the sample above is oversimplification of my code, only to check on how to handle data

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with the fact that you didn't specify a mapping value. Try  `@RequestMapping(value="/foo", ...GET)` and `@RequestMapping(value="/foo", ...PUT)` respectively

The documentation writes:

> If you have a single default method (without explicit path mapping), then all requests without a more specific mapped method found will be dispatched to it. If you have multiple such default methods, then the method name will be taken into account for choosing between them.

About the error - you need to add the aopalliance jar to your classpath.

Comment: I defined the mapping only on class level. The method will handle the requests.

Comment: @Rudy Dajoh well, try that - it might be an issue with choosing which method to invoke.

Comment: Ok, I've tested it using `@RequestParam`, the one being invoked was getCity, while removing all parameters would correctly invokes putCity without parameter. I can't capture the parameters using HttpServletRequest though. I've just seen an `invalid request` error using `@RequestParam` which may be a reason why putCity failed and invoked getCity instead, and may be the main problem here is because Java couldn't retrieve any parameters from request. I've tried with RoR to capture the data, and RoR could received all its form data correctly. So, I am sure the problem lies in Java.

Comment: @Rudy Dadjoh - my idea was to try by setting the request mapping value. Did you try that?

Comment: yes... it adds my existing path with your path. Still, using same requestmapping value gave me the `getCity`. When I tried to use `/foo1` and `/foo2` it gave me `invalid request` when I tried `PUT`. If I intentionally gave `/foo2` with `GET`, it gave me `404 not found`

Comment: @Rudy Dajoh aha. please show the `@RequestMapping` on the class level.

Comment: @Rudy Dajoh try with removing the request mapping from the class level, and copy it to both methods. To see if it is a definition parsing problem.

Comment: The same.. result on browser is `400 bad request` with `@RequestParam`, and when I try with `HttpServletRequest` is `put request` but I can't get any parameter. Is there some possibility that any data sent from browser using `PUT` request was truncated somehow?

Comment: I caught an error on log file.. is this have anything to do with it? What is aopalliance for?

Comment: @Rudy Dajoh you need aopalliacne jar on the classpath.

Comment: Now I got this: HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 How can I see the request sent in raw format?

Comment: I just checked on Spring forum, it seems some people are also having this problem http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=86425