# Spring and ExtJS "400 Bad Request" with PUT but not with POST

Tags: java, javascript, spring, extjs

I'm trying to send parameters with PUT from JavaScript to a Spring application. Here is the @RequestMapping in a Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "toggle-paid-action", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public final String togglePaid(@RequestParam final int year, 
    @RequestParam final String docType, @RequestParam final int number) {
```

And here the JavaScript snippet that is supposed to send those parameters.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    params: {year: year, docType: docType, number: number},
    url: 'toggle-paid-action',
    method: 'PUT',
```

However, I get a "400 Bad Request" every time with description "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()".

If I check with Firebug, there is a PUT tab with all my parameters, and the parameters are correctly spelled since if I switch from PUT to POST on both sides everything works.

I was wondering what could be the problem, is PUT limited to @PathVariable parameters, or it can send also POST-like parameters?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521173/spring-framework-enable-put-method)? It suggests to use `String` or a model class rather than `int/Integer` and some info about default methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can't pass parameters to spring using request method PUT as there is a restriction in the servlet API. You can only work with PUT methods implementing a restful service, passing data as the **request body**, in other cases (like Spring MVC Databinding) PUT won't work.
see [SpringMVC is not recognizing request body parameters if using PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894270/springmvc-is-not-recognizing-request-body-parameters-if-using-put)

JIRA:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7414

Comment: ah interesting, so this is a limitation of the Servlet API, but the HTTP protocol would allow it, I suppose. I will experiment with @RequestBody, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This, as suggest above, seems to be a bug in `spring/servlet API`. In reality `PUT` requests are supposed to work on `Request Body (or payload)` and not on Request Parameters. In that sense, servlet API & spring's handling is correct.

Having said that, a better and much easier workaround is to pass no data element from your `javascript/jQuery` call and pass your parameters as part of the url itself. meaning, set parameters in the url field the way you would do in a `GET` call.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "yoururl" + "?param1=param2Val&..",
            type: "PUT",
            data: "",
            success: function(response) {
                // ....
            }
     });
```

now this works for simple parameters, i guess, will not work for complex JSON types. Hope this helps.